# How can I make OS X recognize new file extensions?

Tags: macos, finder, uti

In Finder.app, you can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to edit the name of the currently selected file or folder.

OS X will automatically select only the file name part, not the extension:

[image]

This is very useful, because that way you can just start typing the new name, without worrying about accidentally changing the file extension.

However, this only seems to work for “known” file types. If you try it with an unknown extension, the whole file name (including the extension) gets selected:

[image]

I tried mapping an application that can open all `.bar` files via <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> → “Change All”, but I still get the behavior described above.

Where is the list of “known” file types stored? Is there a way to make OS X recognize new file types?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/a/246493/3218) worked for me:

> You need to browse to the application that you’d like to use to open these files, and edit its bundle. Right-click the application to handle these file extensions and select *Show Package Contents*. Navigate to `Contents`, and edit `Info.plist`. You might need *Property List Editor*, which is part of Apple’s developer tools. If you’re lucky, it’s in XML format. Edit this file’s `CFBundleDocumentTypes` and add an entry for the extension that you want.

I used TextEdit as the default application to open `.bar` files. The only thing I did differently was change the XML that went in TextEdit’s `Info.plist` to:

```
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>bar</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>BarDocument</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Bar Document</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Document</string>
    </dict>
```

…and then I used [LSRefresh.app](https://www.iospirit.com/blog/2006/10/LSRefresh-a-simple-solution-to-Launch-Services-related-problems) to refresh TextEdit in the launch services database. Then it worked as you suggested, although it will probably break the code signature of Textedit (and any other signed application) on Lion.

Comment: `CFBundleTypeExtensions` is a legacy key which became [deprecated in OS X 10.5](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-101685-TPXREF107). The preferred method since 2007 is to declare new UTIs, as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/#UTIs) and described in [my answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47319/how-can-i-make-os-x-recognize-new-file-extensions#answer-175395).

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to downvote this because this is bad advice.  Not only is it unwise to tamper with an app bundle (running the risk of bizarre side effects or worse), but it can also completely wreck the copy of the app.  You note that this process does invalidate the code signature but fail to point out that on macOS versions that support sandboxing (10.7+), **a sandboxed app with an invalid signature _cannot be launched or used in any way._**

Comment: @binarybob, What I don't understand is why don't you simply rightclick the file `xxx.bar` and select `open with`?

Comment: @Bob, What's app standboxing?

Comment: @Pacerier App sandboxing is a security feature of macOS that completely isolates apps from the system and each other, with a very short list of "entitlements" that details specifically what apps _are_ allowed to do.  That list of entitlements is embedded in the code signature and validated every time the app is run, ensuring that apps' capabilities cannot be tampered with, either by accident or by an attack.   See [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html) for a technical explanation.

Comment: Let me reinforce @Bob's comment. Since at least macOS Catalina, and probably earlier, tampering with _any_ file inside a package (= macOS app) will _immediately_ and _irreversibly_ prevent that app from launching. The only way to restore it is to install it from scratch (overwriting whatever changes you've made). See [the reply by @TachyonVortex](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/175395/27729) for a more convoluted, but **safer** alternative to this issue.

Answer (score 44):

## UTIs and Launch Services

> Where is the list of “known” file types stored?

The official term for "file types" is
[Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html)
(UTIs), and the database of UTIs is maintained by
[Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html).

Using the [Terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_%28OS_X%29),
you can view the contents of the Launch Services database using the `lsregister` tool, which is stored at:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister
```

Instead of specifying that long path every time you want to run `lsregister`, you can temporarily add its directory to your `PATH`:

```
PATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support:"$PATH"
```

and then you can run `lsregister` by simply entering:

```
lsregister
```

To view the contents of the Launch Services database:

```
lsregister -dump
```

---

## Declaring New UTIs

> Is there a way to make OS X recognize new file types?

This Apple article,
["Declaring New Uniform Type Identifiers"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html),
provides useful information on how to do this. Here's the complete process:

### 1. Create a dummy application

Create a dummy application to register with Launch Services:

- Open [AppleScript Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript_Editor) (located in OS X's **Utilities** folder).
- Save a new empty script somewhere (eg: on your Desktop), setting its **File Format** to **Application**.

### 2. Open its Info.plist file

- Locate your new dummy application in the Finder.
- Right-click on it, and select **Show Package Contents** from the popup menu.
- Open its **Contents** folder.
- Open the **Info.plist** file in a text editor (eg: [TextEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit)).

### 3. Add your new UTI

There's a choice of two keys:

- `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` – for your own custom filename extensions.
- `UTImportedTypeDeclarations` – for filename extensions which already exist but aren't recognised by OS X.

Choose the key which is most appropriate for your needs.

Then in the **Info.plist** file, before the final two lines (`</dict></plist>`), add this code:

```
<key>KEY</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>IDENTIFIER</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>EXTENSION</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

making the following changes:

- Replace `KEY` with your chosen key (either `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` or `UTImportedTypeDeclarations`).
- Replace `IDENTIFIER` with a suitable reverse-DNS identifier:

  - Exported – Something like `com.mycompany.mytype`
  - Imported – For [id Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id_Software)'s
    [Doom WAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_WAD) format, a suitable identifier would be `com.idsoftware.wad`
- Replace `EXTENSION` with the filename extension (without the leading dot), eg: `wad`.

This is the minimum code necessary for Launch Services to accept your new UTI.
You can also add the following optional properties:

- `UTTypeConformsTo` – See the Appendix below.
- `UTTypeDescription` – A user-visible description, which will be displayed in the Finder.
- `UTTypeIconFile` – If you add an [Apple Icon Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format)
  file to the **Contents/Resources** folder in your dummy application, and add its filename in this property,
  then files which have your new filename extension will use this icon.
- `UTTypeReferenceURL` – The URL of a reference document describing this type.

Here's a complete example showing all the optional properties:

```
<key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.idsoftware.wad</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>wad</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Doom WAD file</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>DoomWAD.icns</string>
        <key>UTTypeReferenceURL</key>
        <string>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_WAD</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

### 4. Register your new UTI with Launch Services

Run this command in the Terminal:

```
lsregister <PATH_TO_APP>
```

replacing `<PATH_TO_APP>` with the path to your dummy application, eg:

```
lsregister ~/Desktop/MyDummyApp.app
```

If you now create a file with your new filename extension, and then select it in the Finder
and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the Finder should automatically select only the filename part, not the extension.

If you view the contents of the Launch Services database:

```
lsregister -dump
```

you should find your new UTI listed:

```
type    id:            50364
        bindableKey:   12608
        generation:    1
        uti:           com.idsoftware.wad
        description:   Doom WAD file
        flags:         imported  active  apple-internal  untrusted
        icon:          DoomWAD.icns
        conforms to:   public.data
        tags:          .wad
```

If you later want to unregister your new UTI, pass the `-u` option to `lsregister`:

```
lsregister -u ~/Desktop/MyDummyApp.app
```

---

## Appendix: UTI hierarchy and conformance

OS X declares a hierarchy of UTIs which are listed here:
[System-Declared Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html).

Here are a few UTIs in the hierarchy:

- `public.content`

  - `public.text`

    - `public.rtf`
    - `public.html`
    - `public.xml`
    - `public.plain-text`
    - `public.source-code`

      - `public.c-source`
      - `public.c-header`
      - `com.sun.java-source`
  - `public.image`

    - `public.jpeg`
    - `public.tiff`
    - `public.png`
  - `public.audiovisual-content`

    - `public.movie`
    - `public.audio`

Each UTI "conforms to" its parent UTI:

> For example, the UTI `public.html`, which defines HTML text, conforms to the
>   base text identifier, `public.text`. In this case, conformance lets applications
>   that can open general text files identify HTML files as ones it can open as well.
>   ([ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH202-SW4))

When creating a new UTI, it's a good idea to set the `UTTypeConformsTo` property to one
of the existing UTIs.

For example, if your new UTI is a type of source code,
then you should set the `UTTypeConformsTo` property to `public.source-code`,
so that it can be opened by any applications which can open
`public.source-code` or `public.plain-text` or `public.text` files.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the editor that is asociated with the file extension?

Comment: To the OP: this ought to be flagged as the accepted suggestion. See @Bob's comment.

Comment: To @gr4nt3d: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/323743/27729 below for what you wish to do.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Select the file with unrecognized extension (say, `.txt`).
2. Right click and select `Get Info` or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to display the information window.
3. Click on the disclosure indicator besides **Open with:** to open detailed view. Select the desired app from the drop down. This will associate the document with the chosen application (For e.g. TextEdit).
4. Click on the **Change All...** button. It will first show a dialogue box asking to confirm your intent and will link all `.txt` documents to open with TextEdit, and leave the extension un-selected when you hit return on the document's name.