# What determines the label displayed in the "Kind" column of an OS X finder window and in search box labeled "Kind"?

Tags: finder

What determines the label displayed in the "Kind" column of an OS X finder window and in search box labeled "Kind"?

For example, I use LaTeX, and all files with the extension .tex are labeled "LaTeX" in the finder Window and I have them set to open with SublimeText.

Did SublimeText set the file "Kind"?

Also, if I want to search for all file of type "LaTeX" the Finder search box only gives me a limited set of options for "Kind", e.g. Application, Archive, Document, etc. Can I change that option box to show "LaTeX".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CFBundleDocumentTypes

To answer your first and second question:

OS X applications are able to register document types with the system. They do so by declaring those document types within the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` section in the `Info.plist` file which resides inside the application bundle.

For example, you can find the entry for the *LaTeX* kind by opening Terminal.app and invoking this command:

```
$ grep LaTeX -B4 -A7 /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

The resulting XML chunk defines the three-way relationship between the application, the name of the bundle type (aka *Kind*), and the respective file extensions:

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>LaTeX</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
    <array>
        <string>tex</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
    <string>TeX</string>
</dict>
```

For more details about document types, see the section [CFBundleDocumentTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-101685-TPXREF107) in the document *Registering the File Types Your App Supports* from Apple’s Developer Library.

### Spotlight searches

To answer your third question:

> Can I change that option box to show "LaTeX"

Open the drop down box and choose *Other.* A text box appears; type the name of the file kind you wish to search for, or any substring of it.

If the *Other* option won’t appear in the drop-down list, you might need to enable the option first by going to System Preferences » Spotlight and ticking the checkbox next to *Other*.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get 'LaTeX' to appear as an option in the drop down list?

Comment: @pheon Not that I know of. I’ve found an interesting alternative to the drop-down list though: it’s possible to type `kind:latex` directly into the search field. ([Source](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2013/04/advance-searches-in-finder-and-spotlight.html))

Comment: [CFBundleTypeExtensions is a legacy key which became deprecated in OS X 10.5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47319/how-can-i-make-os-x-recognize-new-file-extensions/175395#comment206787_47366). See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/175395/24324) for a more recent solution.