# How I can I open CSV/Excel files in Finder and have them open in the Google Sheets editor?

Tags: google-chrome, big-sur

On my work computer, I'd like to be able to open CSV and Excel files from within Finder and have them load directly into the Google Sheets editor.

Setting Finder to open the files in Google Chrome does load the file in Google Drive, but you still need to go one more step and click "Save as Google Sheets".

[image]

Comment: I'm too lazy to workout a full answer but I suspect you could do it following [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/175395/27319). You'd need to make an AppleScript that launches your browser with the correct Google Sheets URL and associate it with .CSV files and/or excel files

Answer (score 1):

1. If you haven't done yet, install Google Drive for Desktop
2. Find CSV/Excel file using Finder from Google Drive mounted unit (you might have to move your CSV/Excel files to Google Drive first)
3. Right click the file and select **Open with Google Sheets**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it’s possible directly via finder. For convenience, you can use chrome to install the gdoc web app, then launch the app from launchpad and click open, then drag the file in.

When using backup and sync, the extension .docs does exactly what you want, but that’s just a rebranded URL file.

Answer (score -3):

You can download Google Drive For desktop, then set `.csv` as default to Backup and Sync. (srry i said backup n sync i meant google drive)

Comment: Google Backup and Sync has been replaced by Google Drive - How do you down load √?